# How to remove nodes from XML file as command line with namespace?

Tags: sed, xml

I have an `xml` file that contains the tag `</w:rPr>` several times.

It is used like this

```
  <w:rPr>
      TO REMOVE
  </w:rPr>
```

However the content between the tag itself is sometimes different. Could there be a way to use sed or something other to delete everything between `<w:rPr>` and `</w:rPr>` and then both tags as well?

The relevant namespace

```
xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main"
```

And the file itself (formatted, valid XML)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<root xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main">
    <w:lvl w:ilvl="0">
      <w:rPr>
          TO REMOVE
      </w:rPr>
      <w:rPx>
        <w:rFonts w:ascii="Symbol" w:hAnsi="Symbol" w:hint="default"/>
      </w:rPx>
    </w:lvl>
</root>
```

Comment: can't be done. Too many characters.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## TL;DR

**please**, never ever use [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) for this task !

Everytime you use `sed` for `html` or `xml`, you kill a kitty

[image]

### It's a task for [xmlstarlet](/questions/tagged/xmlstarlet)

(a proper XML parser) and his friend [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath), like this:

```
xmlstarlet ed \
           -L \
           -N w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" \
           -d '//w:rPr' file.xml
```

#### A bit of explanations :

- `-L` edit the file *on the fly* like `sed -i`
- `-N` set the *XML namespace*, if needed
- `-d` remove nodes matching `xpath` expression

Check `xmlstarlet edit --help`

### Using [`basex`](http://basex.org)

**Pure XQuery solution**:

```
$ cat XQuery
declare namespace w = "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main";    
copy $input := doc("/dev/stdin")
modify delete node $input//w:rPr
return $input

$ basex XQuery < file.xml
```

### Using `XQuery` and `xidel`:

With [limited XQuery capabilities](https://sourceforge.net/p/videlibri/mailman/message/37801670/).

```
xidel --xml --xquery '
    declare namespace w = "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main";
    x:replace-nodes(//w:rPr, ())
' file.xml
```

## theory :

> According to the compiling theory, XML/HTML can't be parsed using regex based on [finite state machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine). Due to hierarchical construction of XML/HTML you need to use a [pushdown automaton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushdown_automaton) and manipulate [LALR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LR_parser) grammar using tool like [YACC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yacc).

#### realLife©®™ everyday tool in a [shell](/questions/tagged/shell) :

You can use one of the following :

- [xmllint](http://xmlsoft.org/xmllint.html) often installed by default with `libxml2`, xpath1
- [xmlstarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/docs.php) can edit, select, transform... Not installed by default, XPath1
- [xpath](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::XPath) installed via Perl's module XML::XPath, XPath1
- [BaseX](http://basex.org/) not installed by default, package `basex`, full XQuery 3.1
- [xidel](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/xidel.html) XPath3, partial XQuery 3 (no Update)
- [saxon-lint](https://github.com/sputnick-dev/saxon-lint) my own project, wrapper over @Michael Kay's Saxon-HE Java library, XPath3

#### or you can use high level languages and proper libs, I think of :

[python](/questions/tagged/python)'s [`lxml`](http://lxml.de/) (`from lxml import etree`)

[perl](/questions/tagged/perl)'s [`XML::LibXML`](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/XML-LibXML/LibXML.pod), [`XML::XPath`](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::XPath), [`XML::Twig::XPath`](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Twig), [`HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath`](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath)

[ruby](/questions/tagged/ruby) [nokogiri](/questions/tagged/nokogiri), [check this example](https://sputnick.fr/scripts/parsing-HTML-with-NokogiriXpath.rb.html)

[php](/questions/tagged/php) `DOMXpath`, [check this example](https://sputnick.fr/scripts/parsing-HTML-with-DOMXpath.php.html)

---

Check: [Using regular expressions with HTML tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

[image]

Comment: Would it help to provide you with the complete file? Tbh I don't know anything about xml. Hence my thought of using sed.

Comment: Sure it will help ! :)

Comment: Schroedinger's kitty?

Comment: Thank you so much! This has been helpful and saved me!!