# an XML without LF want to make it pretty using sed command in shell

Tags: shell-script, shell, sed

I have a structure of a project in my git repository and would like to run a shell command in git bash to replace all the `>` with `>\n` (LF).
I tried the following command:

```
find . -name '*.xml' -exec sh -c 'sed 's/>/>\n/g "$0"' '{}' ';'
```

meaning to replace the above sets (`>` with `>\n`) in all xml files found in my project.

I don't know what I am doing wrong since I land in the editor with cursor ">"...
(just making it pretty in an editor - e.g. Note++ is easy with plugins for XMLTools but I want my files altered to have in them the LF after each XML tag)

When I write the command for a file only - it works nice:

```
$ sed 's/>/>\n/g' MyFile.xml
```

Comment: Did you try running `xmlstarlet fo MyFile.xml`?

Comment: Teo, you've an odd number of single quotes in that line so it can't run. Please double-check what you've shown us. If this is the issue and you've been getting errors when you try to run it, please tell us!

Comment: @roaima:I tried to simplify my command:
find . -name '*.xml' -print0 | xargs -0 -I '{}' sed 's/>/>\n/g ' '{}' 
It worked on the Git Bash but nothing happend in the files...

Comment: Of course not. You didn't ask that ↑ to change anything. But your _question as posted_ has a syntax error on the `find ...` line. Please address that or make it clear that the reason it's not working for you is that you're getting an error that you can't fix.

Comment: Thanks @roaima:I tried to simplify my command:
find . -name '*.xml' -print0 | xargs -0 -I '{}' sed 's/>/>\n/g ' '{}' 
It worked on the Git Bash but nothing happend in the files...
Still stuck!
I would be thankful if you could show me how to correc my statements because I am new to Linux and don't have a clue how to imbedd quotes in quotes - as in my original sed statement.

Comment: So is the problem that you're getting an error when you try to run it? If so PLEASE TELL US !!!

Comment: I don't know what I am doing wrong since I land in the editor with cursor ">".

Comment: Editor? What editor?

Comment: I suppose it is from sed(?) this cursor ">" - I exit from there with CTRL-C
to reach again the "$" - cursor from git bash

Comment: Oh I see. No, that's the secondary prompt from your shell. In this instance it's because you have an odd number of quoting characters in your command, so the shell needs the closing quote to complete your command.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's a bad idea to use `sed` for this, what you seems to do is to *format* the XML file.

It's a simple task for any XML parser, ex :

```
xmllint --format file.xml
```

This utility is often installed by default on GNU Linux, or with the package `libxml2`

or

```
xmlstarlet format file.xml
```

Comment: I work with Git Bash in windows: 
Message: bash: "xmlstarlet: command not found"

Comment: Because the command is not installed. AFAIK you can install it for windows. Is `xmllint` is installed ?

Comment: I work with Git Bash in windows: 
Message: bash: "xmlstarlet: command not found"
(same with xmllint)
Could you please elaborate on why is a bad ideea to use sed?
And I wonder how to install xmllint in my environment - Git Bash for windows...

Comment: "Why is it a bad idea" -- good discussion here: [Why it's not possible to use regex to parse HTML/XML: a formal explanation in layman's terms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6751105/why-its-not-possible-to-use-regex-to-parse-html-xml-a-formal-explanation-in-la)

Comment: https://sourceforge.net/projects/xmlstar/files/xmlstarlet/1.6.1/xmlstarlet-1.6.1-win32.zip/download

Comment: 'why it's a bad idea': check a post that I wrote yesterday here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/561017/how-to-remove-nodes-from-xml-file-as-command-line/561018#561018

Comment: @Giles Quenot - Thanks for the lessons:
- the WHY not use regex to parse XML (good deep discution)
- the link to download xmlstarlet from sourceforge.net - it worked except that now I am struggling to use the command "xml" and it seems to work nice with other commands (e.g. ls) and even with fo but I get a nice xml with LF inserted only on the terminal since my question was (and I am still puzzled) how to alter all my xml files in a subdirectory! I tried it for a file and the file remains unaltered (without the LF inserted!...)

Comment: SOLVED - worked well with:
xml format source.xml >dest.xml
(for one file)
I still don't know how to do it for all the .xml files in the subfolders...(?)

Comment: Like this: `find . -type f -iname '*.xml' -exec bash -c 'xml format "$1" > /tmp/xml.xml && mv /tmp/xml.xml "$1"' -- {} \;`

Comment: @Gilles - many Thanks! You sent me on the right track on learning shell commands and sintax! Your comment are pro and you seem to be a good teacher.
I ran your command and it looks good - it works properly, but I am not sure what you are doing - i.e. I don't fully understand the end of your command:
after &&... I just gues that "&&" concatenates two shell commands (here mv after xml) but what really "-- {} \" does must be somehow connected with removing the tmp subdir (which I just noticed that dissapeared! - wow).

Comment: If you can please give me some hints about that. ( I was struggling yesterday with find and did unsuccessfully my best;
#find . -type f -name '*.tmp' -print0 |xargs -0 -I '{}' mv '{}' '{%.tmp}' ->but erases all tmp files!)

Comment: Teo: Feel free to mail me with your request